# a Problem in downgrade a project's references from Crystal Reports 11 to 10

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, crystal-reports

In order to downgrade from crystal reports “11” to “10” I had uninstall all related Crystal report products & removed the project’s references
After that I get the new assemblies out from the GAC folder and used them
But while building my project I faced some errors like
-   The compiler did not found this class “CrystalDecisions.Web.CrystalReportSource”
-   The compiler did not found this EventArgs “CrystalDecisions.Web.ErrorEventArgs”
The type or namespace name 'CrystalReportSource' does not exist in the namespace 'CrystalDecisions.Web' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Is what I did to downgrade is the right way, Please advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have the option of reinstalling Crystal 10?

When you re-add the references to Crystal 10 in your project, it is customary to add references to the Crystal files in the GAC, not in another folder. You shouldn't need to copy the files out.

Then, normally, you install the Crystal redistributable on the client for use at runtime; you don't deploy the Crystal assemblies with your project.

Comment: Thank you for your replay
I got the assemblies out from the GAC folder because I don’t know how to refer to them directly from the GAC
What about these missing classes in version 10
- class “CrystalDecisions.Web.CrystalReportSource”
- EventArgs “CrystalDecisions.Web.ErrorEventArgs”
Do you have any idea

Comment: @Mohamed - In your VS project, the Add Reference dialog should have a ".Net" tab. Everything on that tab is registered on your system. Select the Crystal Reports assemblies and add them to your project. That will add references to them wherever they sit on your system.  Be sure you add `CrystalDecisions.Web`, since that seems to be what you're missing. It seems you're either missing references or, if you did any development with CR 11, it's possible that `CrystalDecisions.Web.CrystalReportSource` and `CrystalDecisions.Web.ErrorEventArgs` didn't exist in CR 10.